# Problems with pointcloud generation

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

In my Structure form Motion approach I am encountering some strange problems when creating the point cloud from the disparity image (which also is not correct I guess)

Before I show you the sourcecode, here are the input images, the rectified images, the disparity image and the pointcloud.

Left image
[image: Left image]

Right image
[image: Right image]

Rectified left
[image]

Rectified right
[image]

Disparity image
[image]

PointCloud
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx9OKnxaua8kcGFULW5raE1pdVU/edit?usp=sharing

As the rectified images are quiete good (imho) I am not going to post the code for rectification. 
Here is how I am creating the disparity image:

```
private Mat createDisparityMap(Mat rectLeft, Mat rectRight){    

    // Converts the images to a proper type for stereoMatching
    Mat left = new Mat();
    Mat right = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rectLeft, left, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(rectRight, right, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Create a new image using the size and type of the left image
    Mat disparity = new Mat(left.size(), left.type());

    int numDisparity = (int)(left.size().width/8); 

    StereoSGBM stereoAlgo = new StereoSGBM(
            0,    // min DIsparities
            numDisparity, // numDisparities
            11,   // SADWindowSize
            2*11*11,   // 8*number_of_image_channels*SADWindowSize*SADWindowSize   // p1
            5*11*11,  // 8*number_of_image_channels*SADWindowSize*SADWindowSize  // p2

            -1,   // disp12MaxDiff
            63,   // prefilterCap
            10,   // uniqueness ratio
            0, // sreckleWindowSize
            32, // spreckle Range
            false); // full DP
    // create the DisparityMap - SLOW: O(Width*height*numDisparity)
    stereoAlgo.compute(left, right, disparity);

    Core.normalize(disparity, disparity, 0, 256, Core.NORM_MINMAX);

    return disparity;
}
```

And here is how I am creating the pointcloud using reprojectImageTo3D and later save it as obj file.

```
private Mat reprojectDisparityImageTo3D(Mat disparity, Mat Q){
    publishProgress("reprojecting");
    Mat outputImage = new Mat();        
    Calib3d.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, outputImage, Q);
    return outputImage;
}


private void savePointCloud(Mat pcl){
    publishProgress("Saving .obj file");
    try {
        // open the file for writing to (.obj file)
        File datei = new File(activity.getProjectFolder()+"/../", "poincloud.obj");
        if(!datei.exists())
                datei.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(datei);
        OutputStreamWriter oStream = new OutputStreamWriter(outStream);

        for(int w = 0; w < pcl.size().width; w++){
            for(int h = 0; h < pcl.size().height; h++){
                double[] values = new double[1];
                values = pcl.get(w, h);
                if(values != null)
                    if(values.length >= 3)
                        oStream.append("v " + String.valueOf(values[0]) + " " +String.valueOf(values[1]) + " " +String.valueOf(values[2]) + " " +  "\n");
            }
        }
        oStream.close();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Can someone help me and point out why the result looks like it looks? I assumed the following:

- The disparitymap is more dense, with lesser errors. It looks like object near to the camera are heaving a smaller disparity...
- The reprojected image/pointcloud should represent the scene, so that I can "see" the bottle or the  "oster-minis" with different depth.